# Graph adjacency list implementation in C++

Tags: c++, algorithm, graph

I have been playing around with an adjacency list implementation of a graph class, on which I'd like to be able to run a build and test several graph algorithms. The code I have below works and I have been able to implement BFS, DFS, Dijkstra and Prim's algorithms, but I'm not very satisfied with it and would very much appreciate criticism.

One of the key problems that I can see is that the neighbours of a `node` are private and therefore to traverse them inside a function (i.e. Dijkstra) I need to make this function a `friend` of the `node` class.  I suspect that I should implement smart pointers to solve this but before I do this I'd like to consider other suggestions (maybe custom iterators?).

I also think there is a problem with how the nodes are being initialised, as I would prefer not having to call `setKey` in the `graph::addNode` function.

The node class:

```
class node{
 public:
  node() {}
  node(int k) : key(k){}
  void addNeighbour(int k, int weight = 1){    
    if (this->key == k) return;
    neighbours.push_back(std::make_pair(k,weight));
  }
  inline int getKey() const {return key;}
  inline void setKey(const int k){key = k;}

  void display() const{    
    for (std::list<std::pair<int,int> >::const_iterator it = neighbours.begin(); it != neighbours.end(); ++it){
      std::pair<int,int> entry = *it;
      std::cout << entry.first << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
  }

  friend void bfs(graph &g, int src);
  friend graph prim(graph &g);
  friend void dijkstra(graph &lg, int src);
 private:
  std::list<std::pair<int, int> > neighbours;  //first element in pair corresponds to vertex key, second to the edge weight between them
  int key;
};
```

The graph class:

```
class graph{
 public:
  graph(const int sz) : size(sz), 
                        nodes(sz, node()),
                        directed(false) {}
  void addNode(int key, const std::vector<std::pair<int,int> > &input);
  void display() const;
  node &operator[](const int i){return nodes[i];}
  inline int getSize() const {return size;}
 private:
  std::vector<node> nodes;
  int size;
  bool directed;
};

void graph::addNode(const int key, const std::vector<std::pair<int,int> > &input){

  nodes[key].setKey(key);
  for (std::vector<std::pair<int,int> >::const_iterator it = input.begin(); it != input.end(); ++it){
    std::pair<int,int> entry = *it;
    nodes[key].addNeighbour(entry.first, entry.second);
    if (!directed){
      nodes[entry.first].addNeighbour(key, entry.second);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Overall, it seems good. One problem that I find here though is the lack of vertical spacing at some places. This is very subjective, I agree, but adding a blank line to separate unrelated things can improved readability. I once read somewhere that code should be split into "paragraphs". That's an interesting thought to keep in mind. Giving an example, this is one possible way I would space the method `graph::addNode()`:

```
void graph::addNode(const int key, const std::vector<std::pair<int,int> > &input) {

    nodes[key].setKey(key);

    for (std::vector<std::pair<int,int> >::const_iterator it = input.begin(); it != input.end(); ++it) {

        std::pair<int,int> entry = *it;
        nodes[key].addNeighbour(entry.first, entry.second);

        if (!directed) {
            nodes[entry.first].addNeighbour(key, entry.second);
        }
    }
}
```

---

Another minor point, but you don't need to add `inline` to a method when it is already defined directly inside the class body. In such case, adding the keyword is just unnecessary verbosity.

---

Huge lines like in those for loops:

> ```
> for (std::list<std::pair<int,int> >::const_iterator it = neighbours.begin(); it != neighbours.end(); ++it)
> ```

Can be greatly simplified using `auto` or [*range-based for*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for), if you have access to C++11. Failing that, I'd suggest that you typedef your list type to avoid having to replicate `std::list<std::pair<int,int> >` so many times (remember the [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) principle).

```
typedef std::list<std::pair<int, int> > ListType;
```

---

And as for the search algorithms, you didn't provide any implementation for them, but I don't see a reason why they shouldn't be members of `graph`. Personally, I don't see much purpose for a node to exist on its own without a graph, so I would make `node` a private inner class of `graph` and make all of its members public. Node seems like an implementation detail to me. Your interface apparently deals in terms of `int`s only.

Comment: Thanks, there was some motivation for these choices. Concerning `auto` and the whitespace to improve readability: I agree. I opted not to use `auto` because I wanted to get things correct by hand. 

I wanted to keep the graph algorithms separate from the graph class because it _feels_ like these should be distinct and this seems to be a more modular way to implement things. It isn't clear to me if this is the correct choice from a design perspective but I think it is. I read that nested classes should be avoided but I don't think I have enough experience to make a strong case for that :)

Answer (score 2):

**Initialize `key` in the default constructor of `Node`**

Instead of

```
node() {}
```

I would use

```
node() : key(0) {}
```

**Change `node::display()` to an `operator<<` function**

Instead of

```
void display() const{  ... }
```

I would use:

```
friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, node const& n) { ... }
```

That would allow you change where the data of a `node` is written to. You don't have to hard code `std::cout` as the output stream.

**Change `graph::display()` to an `operator<<` function**

Same rationale as for `node::display`.

**Remove redundant use of `inline`**

When functions are defined inside the body of a class, they are `inline` automatically. Use of `inline` in the following lines is redundant. It doesn't buy you anything. It only clutters the code.

```
inline int getKey() const {return key;}
inline void setKey(const int k){key = k;}
```

I could remove them and use:

```
int getKey() const {return key;}
void setKey(const int k){key = k;}
```

A similar change can be made to `graph::getSize()`

**Removed unnecessary use of `const`**

In the function `node::setKey`, the argument type is `const int`. The `const` in that type has no benefits. I would change it to:

```
void setKey(int k){key = k;}
```

Similar changes can be made to the following functions in `graph`:

```
graph(const int sz) {...}
```

and

```
node &operator[](const int i){return nodes[i];}
```